# How do I connect the vertices in the same mesh/shape?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

I want to get better at 3D modeling and here's my problem: I'm trying to make a mask, but I don't know how to connect vertices to fill the gap.

[image]

https://gyazo.com/87c9de5f88343ac9c12af3aabc6977f7

Comment: You could just make a face, then dissolve one of the edges (X > Dissolve Edge). This is probably faster

Answer (score 3):

Join them Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

To do this select the Top Left Vert.

While holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, Select the bottom left Vert.

Then Do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, and select **At Center**.

Repeat for the Verts at the right.

Answer (score 2):

### Merge at cursor:

With the *3D Cursor* as a *pivot point* enabled select two vertices between the gap, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*, then <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Merge*-->*At Cursor*. Do the same with the other two vertices.

[image]

### Merge at last:

Another method to join the elements preventing the lost of the shape may be using the ***Merge At Last*** option. Select the bottom left vertex, then the top left one (with <kbd>Shift</kbd>) and press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Merge*-->*At Last* or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>-->*At Last*. Do the same with the other two vertices.

[image]

### Making a face and dissolving an edge (Mr Zak's suggestion):

Select all four vertices and fill the gap with a face <kbd>F</kbd>. Then select the bottom edge and press <kbd>X</kbd>-->*Dissolve Edges*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a few vertices to merge or want to perform merging several times during a modelling session, you might find using a combination of [snapping](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/transform_control/precision/snap.html) to vertices and automerge to be a nice solution.

[image: 3dview header]

If you disable snapping, you can hold <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> while moving a vertex to enable snapping on a temporary basis when you want to merge them.